# Jquery Callback Function

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I am having difficulty calling a function after a jQuery AJAX call has finished loading

```
function to_be_executed_last {
    alert("The Call Is Complete");
    //some other stuff
}



$("a.jaxable_link").click(function(){
   $.post($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {

        $('#container').html(data);
 //Execute the function to_be_executed_last here AFTER data has finished loading
  })
})
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fix the signature (missing parenthesis) and call it, like this:

```
function to_be_executed_last() {
  alert("The Call Is Complete");
  //some other stuff
}

$("a.jaxable_link").click(function(){
  $.post($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
    $('#container').html(data);
    to_be_executed_last();
  });
});
```

Comment: 10 seconds. 10. Seconds. ;-) *(Ahead of me, but yours was more complete.)*

Comment: That often calls the function BEFORE the call is complete

Comment: @RisingSun: It never calls the function before the call is complete, not when done properly (as Nick has above). He's called it from within the `success` callback, which *by definition* happens when the call is complete.

Comment: @RisingSun - make sure you have it inside the callback for `$.post()` not *after* `$.post()` and it'll run *after* the `.html()` call.

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call your function. The success callback of all jQuery ajax functions is invoked when the response has been received.